# Mixed uppercase and lowercase in a word

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a list of words and I want to make one character lowercase and one character uppercase. For example, the word information I want to be 
iNfOrMaTiOn
and 
InFoRmAtIoN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU ***sed*** approach:

-- starting with a lowercase letter:

```
s="information"
sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)/\L\1\U\2/g' <<< $s
iNfOrMaTiOn
```

-- starting with an uppercase letter:

```
s="information"
sed -E 's/(.)(.){,1}/\U\1\L\2/g' <<< $s
InFoRmAtIoN
```

---

- `\L` - Turn the replacement to lowercase until a `\U` or `\E` is found
- `\U` - Turn the replacement to uppercase until a `\L` or `\E` is found

---

***gawk*** (GNU awk) approach:

```
awk -v FPAT="[a-z]" '{ s=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { s=s""((i%2)? toupper($i) : $i)} print s }' <<< $s
InFoRmAtIoN
```

- `FPAT="[a-z]"` - pattern representing field value

---

Another *awk* variation using `split()` function:

```
awk  '{ n=split($0,a,""); s=""; 
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++) { s=s""((i%2)? toupper(a[i]): tolower(a[i])) } print s }' <<< $s
InFoRmAtIoN
```

- `split()` returns the number of elements created

Comment: Actually there is a problem at the one witch starts with uppercase, last 2 characters are lowercase. InFoRmAtIoN not InFoRmAtIon

Comment: @antiks, check my update

Comment: Note that `split(string, array, "")` is also a GNU extension, though now widely supported even if not POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly

```
awk '
  {
    for(i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
      c = substr($0, i, 1)
      printf "%s", (i%2 ? toupper(c) : tolower(c))
    }
    print ""
  }' < words.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe '
   ($_ = lc) =~ s/([a-z])([^a-z]*)(.)/\L$1$2\U$3/g;
   $_ .= y/a-zA-Z/A-Za-z/r;
'
```

1. Convert the input line to all lowercase.
2. Change the case alternately to lower then upper of the chars on either side of non-alphabet. It could be nothing also, meaning the alphas are consecutive.
3. Finally, reverse the case using the `y`, aka, `tr` command to get both versions.

## Usage

s="InformatioN";
   echo "$s" | perl -pe '....'

## results:

```
iNfOrMaTiOn
InFoRmAtIoN
```